# Exercises about degrees and lengths of graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory

No multigraphs allowed and $\delta$ represents the smallest degree.

> Let $P$ be a longest simple path in a graph $G$, and let $\lambda$ represent
>   the length of $P$. ($P$ contains $\lambda$ edges and $\lambda + 1$ vertices.)
>
> (a) Show that each endpoint of $P$ has degree less than or equal to $\lambda$.
>
> (b) Prove that in any graph with minimum degree $\delta$, there exists a simple path of length $\ge \delta$.

Solution:

(a) The only vertices the endpoints of $P$ can connect to are those on $P.$ Otherwise $P$ will no longer be the longest simple path. Since multigraphs are not allowed, each endpoint can connect to $\lambda$ vertices. Thus the degree of the endpoints is at most $\lambda.$

(b) A graph can't have fewer edges than $\delta.$ Thus $\lambda \ge \delta.$

Does it look correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof of part (a) is basically correct. Typically, we would say that if an endpoint of $P$ has degree larger than $\lambda$, then we can extend $P$ (why?) to a longer path, contradicting the assumption that $P$ was the longest (you could even use "maximal") path.

Your proof of part (b) is wrong. Just because a graph has $\delta$ edges does not mean it has a simple path of length $\delta$ (think of a suitably small complete graph). You should try to use part (a) to prove part (b).

Hint for part (b):

> Let $P$ be a longest simple path of a longest simple graph $G$. Let $G$ have minimum degree $\delta$ and let $v$ be an endpoint of $P$. Using part (a), what can you say about $d(v)$ and the length of $P$? What can you say about $\delta$ and $d(v)$?

Note that the typically way of proving part (b) is by "greedily growing" a path.

Comment: The maximum degree is $\lambda$ because otherwise $P$ is not the longest simple path and since the minimum degree is $\delta$, we have $\lambda \ge \delta?$

Comment: The maximum degree of the graph is certainly not guaranteed to be $\lambda$. Read my hint again.

Comment: A graph $G$ with degree $\delta$ will have at least $\delta + 1$ vertices so $G$ has a simple path of length at least $\delta$ and since $P$ is the longest simple path it can't be smaller than $\delta?$

Comment: Just because a graph has $\delta+1$ vertices doesn't mean that it has a simple path of length $\delta$. I'll rephrase my hint so it is more explicit.

Comment: $\delta \le d(v) \le \lambda?$